# In CakePhp - Drop Down box's values are not saved in DB in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP version is `2.x`. I have a Three Model

> 1) room_categories(id,title)
>   2) room_capacities(id,name)
>   3) room_details(id,name,room_categories_id,room_capacities_id)

This is my controller :

```
class RoomDetailsController extends AppController {

var $name = "RoomDetails";
function index(){

    $this->loadModel('RoomCategory');
    $this->loadModel('RoomCapacity');

    $roomcategories = $this->RoomCategory->find('list');
    $roomcapacities = $this->RoomCapacity->find('list');
     $this->set(compact('roomcategories','roomcapacities'));
 }
}
```

In my View File:

```
echo $this->Form->input('roomcategory');

echo $this->Form->input('roomcapacity');
```

Drop down is perfect but when i click on button its also give the message to me that save 
but when i see the database in room_details the entery of room_categories_id has Zero value as well as room_capacities_id also same value that is Zero

so, plz give me solution for this

Comment: try echo "<pre>";print_r($this-data);echo "</pre>"; in your controller form submit action and share the output. thanks

Comment: You really should follow the conventions. Makes your (coding) life so much easier.. Also note that you should be using PHP5 syntax, not PHP4.

Comment: thank to all of my freind who help me to get solution of this problem

Answer (score 2):

room_details table should be:

```
id
name 
room_category_id
room_capacity_id
```

and in the view file

```
echo $this->Form->input('room_category_id');
echo $this->Form->input('room_capacity_id');
```

and in the controller

```
$roomCategories = $this->RoomCategory->find('list');
$roomCapacities = $this->RoomCapacity->find('list');
$this->set(compact('roomCategories','roomCapacities'));
```

Comment: very very thank u to give the answer but when i do like that the drop down list will be empty

Comment: I edited because you have to change also the controller to follow cakePhp conventions